# Converting std::exception_ptr to boost::exception_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I want to use `boost::promise::set_exception()` that expects a `boost::exception_ptr`. The problem is that `boost:exception_ptr` seems to work correctly only if I wrap *all* my throws with `enable_current_exception` and I want to avoid that. (I wouldn't be able to do that for 3rd party libraries anyway.) 
I use `std::exception_ptr/std::current_exception` throughout my code, so I am looking for a way to pass `std::exception_ptr` where a `boost:exception_ptr` is expected. 
Something that does the following, but compiles:

```
boost::exception_ptr convert(std::exception_ptr ex) {
    try {
        std::rethrow_exception(ex);
    }
    catch(auto& ex) {
        try {
            throw boost::enable_current_exception(ex);
        }
        catch (...) {
            return boost::current_exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Context:

I need `boost::future::then()`, so using a `std::promise` is unfortunately not an option (at least at the moment)

If you know a way to make `boost::exception_ptr` to rely on gcc 4.8 compiler support instead of `enable_current_exception` that would be an acceptable solution, as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible. However, I can offer you three possible solutions, sorted by convenience:

## 1. Catch a std::exception

```
boost::exception_ptr convert(std::exception_ptr ex)
{
    try {
        std::rethrow_exception(ex);
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        try {
            throw boost::enable_current_exception(e);
        } catch (...) {
            return boost::current_exception();
        }
    } catch (...) {
        try {
            throw boost::enable_current_exception(std::runtime_error("Unknown exception."));
        } catch (...) {
            return boost::current_exception();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::exception_ptr sep;

    try {
        throw std::runtime_error("hello world");
    } catch (...) {
        sep = std::current_exception();
    }

    boost::exception_ptr bep = convert(sep);

    try {
        boost::rethrow_exception(bep);
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

}
```

This prints `"std::exception"` instead of `"hello world"`, since information from derived classes (in this case, `std::runtime_error`) will be sliced away.

## 2. Throw the std::exception_ptr directly

```
boost::exception_ptr convert(std::exception_ptr ex)
{
    try {
        throw boost::enable_current_exception(ex);
    } catch (...) {
        return boost::current_exception();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::exception_ptr sep;

    try {
        throw std::runtime_error("hello world");
    } catch (...) {
        sep = std::current_exception();
    }

    boost::exception_ptr bep = convert(sep);

    try {
        boost::rethrow_exception(bep);
    } catch (const std::exception_ptr& ep) {
        try {
            std::rethrow_exception(ep);
        } catch (const std::exception& e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

This version prints `"hello world"`, albeit at the cost of an extra `try`/`catch` block. If error handling is done at a central location, maybe displaying a dialog box, I'd go for this solution. Until the boost authors add a constructor from `std::exception_ptr` to `boost::exception_ptr`, that's as good as it gets, I'm afraid.

## Use boost::packaged_task instead of boost::promise

If you can live with using `packaged_task`, this solution works:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 4
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::packaged_task<int()> pt([] () -> int {
        throw std::runtime_error("hello world");
    });
    boost::future<int> f1 = pt.get_future();
    boost::future<int> f2 = f1.then([] (boost::future<int> f) {
        return f.get() + 1;
    });

    boost::thread(std::move(pt)).detach();

    try {
        int res = f2.get();
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Prints `"hello world"` and allows you to use `fut.then()`.

Comment: Solution 3 only works for certain std exceptions, because boost::current_exception proves explicit support for them. If you try it with your custom exception type it does not work (f2.get() throws boost::unknown_exception)

Answer (score 1):

I found not the best solution, but it works.

1. Crete template specialization.

```
namespace boost::exception_detail
{
template<>
class clone_impl< std::exception_ptr > : public clone_base
{
   std::exception_ptr mExceptionPtr;

public:
   clone_impl( std::exception_ptr exception_ptr )
      : mExceptionPtr{ std::move( exception_ptr ) }
   {
   }
   clone_base const* clone() const
   {
      return new clone_impl( *this );
   }

   void rethrow() const
   {
      std::rethrow_exception( mExceptionPtr );
   }
};

int clone_current_exception_non_intrusive( clone_base const*& cloned )
{
   cloned = new clone_impl< std::exception_ptr >{ std::current_exception() };
   return clone_current_exception_result::success;
}
}
```

2. Add `BOOST_ENABLE_NON_INTRUSIVE_EXCEPTION_PTR` definition