# How to rethrow the original exception stored by an std::exception_ptr with a boost::future?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

This is a minimal code example how the exception is moved around using std::exception_ptr:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main() {
    try
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error!");
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        boost::optional<boost::variant<int, std::exception_ptr>> v(std::move(std::current_exception()));
        boost::promise<int> p;
        boost::future<int> f = p.get_future();

        try
        {
            std::rethrow_exception(std::move(boost::get<std::exception_ptr>(std::move(v.get()))));
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            p.set_exception(std::move(std::current_exception()));
        }

        try
        {
            f.get();
        }
        catch (const std::exception &e)
        {
            // This is what I would like to see:
            std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            // This is what I get instead:
            std::cerr << "Unknown error" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to keep the actual object std::runtime_error and get it thrown in the final f.get() statement. Instead, I get an unknown exception which is not derived from std::exception.
When I remove the final catch(...) statement, I get the following output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr>'
```

I would like to avoid any clone/copy operations. I want to keep my std::runtime_error instance and move it until the end (the final f.get() call).
If there is a better way to store any exception than std::exception_ptr, please tell me and I will use it instead. Folly uses the class template folly::exception_wrapper but I don't know any other standard type.

You can check out the files of the original project here: https://github.com/tdauth/cpp-futures-promises/tree/master/src/advanced
The different rethrows are required because I use the wrapper type Try and the method Promise::tryComplete.

Comment: There's a whole lot of code in here

Comment: I get that you wrote this code and it did not work.  But before posting it here, produce a [mcve].  90%+ of the above code looks irrelevant to your problem; delete stuff until you have about 5 lines left and the same bug.

Comment: sry guys, I have modified the original post to show the actual problem.

Comment: Well, in the original Code I cannot just call throw. This is a modified example to demonstrate the error. I have to store the exception somehow and rethrow it later. I don't know if std::exception_ptr is the correct way to store exceptions but since exceptions do not have to inherit std::exception, I have to use it?

Comment: Maybe I have to use https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work with https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html

I should not have used std::exception_ptr with Boost.Thread.

There is also a closed (Won't Fix) ticket for this feature: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/9710

And this question how the conversion could be done: [Converting std::exception_ptr to boost::exception_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010388/converting-stdexception-ptr-to-boostexception-ptr)